# Angular 2 callback

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a service that gets the some data from the api this is the code

```
getChallenges(): Observable<IChallenge[]> {
    if (this._challengeUrl != null) {
        return this.http.get(this._challengeUrl)
            .map((res:Response) => <IChallenge[]>res.json())
            .do(data => console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    } else {
        //;
    }
}
```

and i subscribe inside the component where i want to use the service inside ngOnInit and everything is running my fine.

```
this._challengeService.getChallenges()
        .subscribe(challenges => this.challenges = challenges,
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

but now i need to use a filter on the data which should run after ngInit finishes getting the data. this is the filter:

```
filterByLvl(lvl){
    this.challenges.filter((obj)=> obj.level == lvl);
}
```

well my problem is when i try to put the function after the subscribe code i keep getting an empty array because the ngOnInit runs this function first and then gets the data. how can i inverse this? i need to get the data and then run this function.
so any ideas on how to do this? and thanks

Comment: But, where are you keeping this filtered data ? In this example you are throwing away the filtered data.

Comment: omg you are exactly right it was like 4 am and im trying to solve it while my brain was almost dead :). haha i feed so stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried ( don't have access to angular2 at work :-( ), but you can have multiple statements in the lambda function in `subscribe`.

```
this._challengeService.getChallenges()
        .subscribe(challenges =>   
                     { 
                       this.challenges = challenges; 
                       filterByLvl(expert_level); 
                     },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
                   );
```

Comment: thank you this is what i wanted it works and as you mentioned i wasnt storing my filtered data :). really thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

One method would be filter directly when it retrieves the data something like:

```
this._challengeService.getChallenges()
        .subscribe(challenges => this.challenges = challenges.filter((obj)=> obj.level == lvl),
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

***NOTE*** The lvl will be undefined so you've to define it someway with your logic

Comment: hi and thanks for the reply well now it will filter and return only the filtered data and that wont work with me because i want it to get the original data at first and then filter the challenges array

Comment: why not add another param `filtered challenges` and do `challenges => this.challenges = challenges, filteredchallenges => this.filtered = challenges.filter((obj)=> obj.level == lvl)`

Comment: yes. that not good for me because im accessing the this challenge array to get all the 'challenges' based on their level i originally had a button to set the level but i was told that i need the to make the app load the easy questions as default. i really dont want to add new arrays or anything because its working fine with a button the only problem is when i wanted to load after the ngOninit